# How can I get the RTSP stream to show up on multiple devices?

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, rtsp-server

I have a code which uses gstreamer RTSP server and I am trying to create some rtsp streams from images/frames. The implementation works fine and converts the images into an RTSP stream.

The process is I run the script and the server is now active and then I can use the RTSP stream on another machine with my current machine IP.

**Questions:**

1. I would like to know how I can change the rtsp port and take it from the config.json file. For some reason, the default port which gets used is 8554 even though I have not explicitly stated to use that port.
2. Will I be able to use multiple rtsp streams through one RTSP server with the help of different ports? For example, the current implementation I have does not work from more than one machine if I stream the same RTSP URL through VLC.

This is my code so far:

```py
class TestRtspMediaFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
    def __init__(self, source):
        GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory.__init__(self)
        self.source = source

    def do_create_element(self, url):
        image_folder = self.source.get("image_folder", None)

        if image_folder:
            # print('Image folder paths:', image_folder)
            pipeline = f"multifilesrc location={image_folder}/%d.jpg index=1 caps=\"image/jpeg,framerate=30/1\" ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay name=pay0 config-interval=1 pt=96"
        else:
            print("Invalid source. Specify 'image_folder' in the configuration.")
            return None
    
        print("Element created:", pipeline)
        return Gst.parse_launch(pipeline)

class GstreamerRtspServer():
    def __init__(self, sources):
        self.rtspServer = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()
        self.mountPoints = self.rtspServer.get_mount_points()
        self.create_rtsp_streams(sources)

    def create_rtsp_streams(self, sources):
        for source in sources:
            rtsp_port = source["rtsp_port"]
            rtsp_mount_point = source["rtsp_mount_point"]
            print(rtsp_mount_point)
            print(rtsp_port)

            factory = TestRtspMediaFactory(source)
            factory.set_shared(True)
            self.mountPoints.add_factory(rtsp_mount_point, factory)

        self.rtspServer.attach(None)

def main(config_file):
    with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    sources = config.get("sources", [])
    
    s = GstreamerRtspServer(sources)
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    loop.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run RTSP server for multiple video sources.")
    parser.add_argument("--config", required=True, help="Path to the JSON configuration file.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    main(args.config)
```

This is my config.json file:

```
{
    "sources": [
        {
            "image_folder": "/path/to/another/image/folder",
            "rtsp_port": 4000,
            "rtsp_mount_point": "/stream1"
        },
        {
            "image_folder": "/path/to/another/image/folder",
            "rtsp_port": 8555,
            "rtsp_mount_point": "/stream2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I had a look at this solution for the port issue but no luck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662203/setting-output-port-for-rtsp-stream-from-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For setting the port used by the server, you would use method `set_service` of the RtspServer.
2. You don't need to specify different ports for different clients, the RTSP server will negociate with client and manage the actual ports and transport protocols. Clients can select the stream just with the URI using stream1, stream2.

So after modifying your json config file with:

```json
{
    "server": {
            "port": "8556"
    },
        
    "sources": [
        {
            "image_folder": "/home/neville/Documents/convert_rtsp_video/frames",
            "rtsp_mount_point": "/stream1"
        },
        {
            "image_folder": "/path/to/another/image/folder",
            "rtsp_mount_point": "/stream2"
        }
    ]
}
```

and modified your code to:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import json
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst','1.0')
gi.require_version('GstVideo','1.0')
gi.require_version('GstRtspServer','1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, GLib, Gst, GstVideo, GstRtspServer


class TestRtspMediaFactory(GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory):
    def __init__(self, source):
        GstRtspServer.RTSPMediaFactory.__init__(self)
        self.source = source

    def do_create_element(self, url):
        image_folder = self.source.get("image_folder", None)

        if image_folder:
            # print('Image folder paths:', image_folder)
            pipeline = f"multifilesrc location={image_folder}/%d.jpg index=1 loop=1 caps=\"image/jpeg,framerate=30/1\" ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast key-int-max=30 ! rtph264pay name=pay0 config-interval=1 pt=96"

        else:
            print("Invalid source. Specify 'image_folder' in the configuration.")
            return None
    
        print("Element created:", pipeline)
        return Gst.parse_launch(pipeline)
        

class GstreamerRtspServer():
    def __init__(self, server_conf, sources):
        self.rtspServer = GstRtspServer.RTSPServer()
        self.rtspServer.set_service(server_conf["port"])
        print("RTSP Server on port", server_conf["port"]) 
        self.mountPoints = self.rtspServer.get_mount_points()
        self.create_rtsp_streams(sources)

    def create_rtsp_streams(self, sources):
        for source in sources:
            rtsp_mount_point = source["rtsp_mount_point"]
            print(rtsp_mount_point)

            factory = TestRtspMediaFactory(source)
            factory.set_shared(True)
            self.mountPoints.add_factory(rtsp_mount_point, factory)

        self.rtspServer.attach(None)

def main(config_file):
    with open(config_file, 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    server_conf = config.get("server", {})
    sources = config.get("sources", [])
    
    s = GstreamerRtspServer(server_conf,sources)
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    loop.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run RTSP server for multiple video sources.")
    parser.add_argument("--config", required=True, help="Path to the JSON configuration file.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    Gst.init(None)
    main(args.config)
```

it works fine with 2 clients (one for each stream) on localhost and 2 other clients from a remote host.

Comment: Hi @SeB thanks for your answer, it seems to be working now. However, I have a few questions about the pipeline changes you added in. What does ```key-int-max=30``` do? Also, do you have any suggestions for gstreamer docs or rtsp related concepts? The normal gstreamer docs does not have much on it for ease of understanding.

Comment: Also, last time the element used to keep getting created each time when a stream gets started but now it only gets created once, so what do you think the change for that could be? Also, I was looping through vlc at that time so maybe that could be it, ```vlc rtsp://127.0.0.1:8556/stream1 --loop```. FInally, what does ```Gst.init(None)``` relate to?

Comment: About the changes I made to your original pipeline: I used multifilesrc with loop option, as I just had generated image folders with 3000 images. I added key-int-max=30 so that encoder sends a key frame each 30 frames, this helps receiver to quicker display. Gst.init is used to initialize gstreamer (and may also parse some gstreamer args).  For the doc, you would find many from command `gst-inspect-1.0` that will list the plugins and elements available in your host. With a given element as argument, it will display supported input/output formats and properties: `gst-inspect-1.0 x264enc`.

Comment: You may also find many documention on line. See : https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer#where-to-start

Comment: Oh alright, thanks a lot @SeB.

Appreciate the assistance!

Comment: error #1 gi.repository.GLib.GError: gst_parse_error: no element "x264enc" . After fix error #1, new error #2 : method DESCRIBE failed: 503 Service Unavailable