# Streaming Local Video file as RTSP and publish to a port

Tags: docker, ffmpeg, vlc, rtsp

I am trying to setup a single docker that can stream local file as rtsp to a port.

Meaning, within the docker there will be some local videos publish as rtsp to a port of that docker.

Then externally, I can fetch the stream from rtsp://:/mystream

I tried looking into rtsp-simple-server, but it does not seem to have the option of local file streaming, rather it requires first set up a docker server then using ffmpeg to publish video to that server.

Is there a way to achieve the wanted single docker RTSP stream server?

There is another response of building a docker with VLC installed, however it seem to be bulky and overkill, plus the outcome does not seem to be as smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi,**

Most RTSP Servers works like you descripe you have a server instance and publish then a stream to them.

Its not hard to build a own RTSP server with gstreamer and python here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571501/how-to-rtsp-stream-a-video-using-gstreamer-and-python) ,look at the answer, the did exactly what u need.

good start a for a new program project =)